# Rails: Javascript doesn't apply to loaded partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Javascript function that is called when an input element with a certain css class is changed. It works on elements that are present on page load but when I load a partial the function doesn't apply (or doesn't work) on the input elements of the loaded partial.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: Sorry beginner here, how do you do that?